# Error while executing a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SpFillAnswer] 
    @q_Id nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    --SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT Answer, Date_Time, Name 
    FROM Answers, RegUsers
    WHERE Answers.Q_Id = @q_Id 
      AND RegUsers.UserId = (SELECT Answers.User_Id FROM Answers WHERE Answers.Q_Id = @q_Id);
END
```

I have three tables, `RegUsers`, `Answers` and `Questions`.

I have to fetch `Answer` and `Date_Time` from `Answers` table at the same time I have to find out the `User Name` who posted the answer, which is to be fetched from `RegUsers` table.

For this I tried the following code which is running properly for 1 result by the subquery.

But it's giving me an error when more than one results comes out from subquery:

```
(Select Answers.User_Id from Answers where Answers.Q_Id = @q_Id )
```

Please help me out, suggest me another subquery for my desired result.

Thanxx.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `=` to `IN`:

```
Select Answer, Date_Time, Name from 
Answers, RegUsers
where Answers.Q_Id = @q_Id 
and RegUsers.UserId IN (
   Select Answers.User_Id 
   from Answers 
   where Answers.Q_Id = @q_Id );
```

Comment: Thanx Dean for answering. Yeah now "IN" is working but I am having only 2 users who have answered on same questions. but after excuting this query I am getting 4 results instead of 2. each user name is repeating twice with each answers.

Comment: The dangers of using the old `from 
Answers, RegUsers` syntax. You don't have a join between Answers and RegUsers. Rewrite this query using JOIN... ON syntax and your duplicate problem will go away.

Comment: now i tried..... Select Answer, Date_Time, Name from Answers join RegUsers
 on Answers.Q_Id=@q_Id and RegUsers.UserId IN (Select Answers.User_Id from Answers where Answers.Q_Id=@q_Id ); but still the same repeatation occured..

Comment: You need a `JOIN` between the two tables. Otherwise, you are producing a `CROSS JOIN`, or cartesian product. Looking at your code, I would guess that it is `Answers A JOIN RegUsers R ON A.UserId = R.UserID`.